# Does an iPhone immediately download a visual voicemail as soon as it's been received, or only when it's chosen from the list of available messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, voicemail

When using a carrier that makes use of the Visual Voicemail service, upon receiving a voicemail does the iPhone immediately download the message to its internal storage - or is this only done when said message is explicitly chosen from within the "Voicemail" tab of the Phone app?

Answer (score -1):

I’d assume it saves it to its internal memory.